# On the sequence arctan (tan (n))

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $x_n = \arctan (\tan (n))$. Is this sequence dense in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Comment: Did part of your question get corrupted?

Comment: Notice that if $n=k_n\pi+\alpha_n$ with $\alpha_n\in]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$, then $u_n=\alpha_n$.

Comment: This requires clarification since as it is, $x_n=n$, for all $n$ somewhere good.

Comment: @GitGud If $n$ runs through the set of integers, it's wrong. Notice $\tan (\arctan x) = x, \; \forall x\in\Bbb R$, but in general $\arctan (\tan x) \not = x$.

Comment: @arbautjc To me $\arctan$ is the inverse of $\tan$. What definitions are you using?

Comment: The same, but $\tan $ is periodic... $\arctan$ is the inverse of $\tan$ only on $]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$.

Comment: @arbautjc A periodic function can't be injective.

Comment: @GitGud Sure, it's why it has an inverse only on 
\]-pi/2,pi/2\[, where it is bijective. You should draw a graph of $\tan(x)$, or ask [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x%29) to do it for you.

Comment: @arbautjc If you restrict a function to a proper subset of its domain, it's no longer the same function.

Comment: @arbautjc You're stating stuff which isn't standard at all and even if you're right in saying that $\tan$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ (except for a few points) and in saying that $\arctan$ is by definition the inverse of $\tan _{\mid ]-\pi /2, \pi/2[}$, this is exactly the reason why I said in my first comment that the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @arbautjc Unluckily for you, wikipedia's definition of [$\tan$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions) is for $|x|<\pi /2$, not that I care what wikipedia says, but apparently you do. As for what's standard or not, another common way to do things is to define $\tan$ on $]-\pi /2, \pi /2[$ and then periodically extended it to $\mathbb R$. This way $\arctan:=\tan ^{-1}$ and the problem is ill-posed.

Comment: You make no distinction between 'it is defined' and 'it can be defined'. I'm done with this.

Comment: @GitGud I'm a bit puzzled: for you tan must not be periodic otherwise it has no inverse. But then, do you admit sine and cosine are periodic? I hope so, otherwise, you'll have to throw away Fourier series, among others. So, how do you define arcsine and arccosine? I hope you will give up, not the discussion, but your claim that "my stuff isn't standard at all". Mathematics is all about learning and discovering, I hope you have discovered something today. Happy Christmas.

Comment: @GitGud Quite late, but good reading I just stumbled upon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's better than dense, it's *equidistributed:* [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence). You can view the mapping
$$
n\mapsto x_n=\arctan(\tan(n))
$$
as mapping $n$ to its equivalence class in $\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Z}$, where the latter is represented by the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Shifting the representation to the right $\pi/2$ units, the question is equivalent to asking if the numbers $n\bmod \pi \mathbb{Z}$ are dense in the interval $(0,\pi]$ and this is equivalent to asking if the numbers $n/\pi\bmod  \mathbb{Z}$ are dense in $(0,1]$. Since $1/\pi$ is irrational, the *equidistribution theorem* ([see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem)) tells you that the sequence is actually equidistributed in the circle, and this implies that the sequence is dense. For a nice proof of the theorem, see *Fourier Analysis: an Introduction* by Stein and Shakarchi.